# Adding ng-file-upload to a meanjs.org project scaffolded with yeoman

Tags: angularjs, meanjs, ng-file-upload

I had a hard time installing ng-file-upload into my Yeoman scaffolded meanjs.org application.  Bower install did not complete the configuration, and I was getting an error when I tried to load a view using a controller with the 'Upload' dependency.  This was the first time I tried to install a custom module into angular.  I figured I would create this post to give some specific instructions for this case, and to share some general information for people in a similar position to figure out exactly how you extend a scaffolded project with other directives.

In searching for a solution, I found a lot of references to angular-file-upload.  This is either a different package or an old version, so don't use it.

The version of ng-file-upload at the time of this post is: 7.0.17.
I also installed ng-file-upload-shim, which may be required.  It adds file upload support to non-html5 browsers with flash.

STEP 1 - Get the ng-file-upload source.

All modules and directives in angular come in folders.  You can either download the folder from github here: https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload
or use bower/npm.

bower install ng-file-upload-shim --save
bower install ng-file-upload --save
npm install ng-file-upload

Bower handles dependencies for the front end (angular), and puts the folders into public/lib/ng-file-upload and public/lib/ng-file-upload-shim.  If you manually download, this is where it needs to go.

STEP 2 - Update you app configuration files.

This was the part that wasn't obvious.  Bower installs the latest version of the source and any dependencies, but won't update your config files.  At least, it doesn't currently for ng-file-upload.

a) Update config.js, found at /public/modules//config.js

If you use yo meanjs:angular-module, these files are created for you.  You'll see a line that looks like:

var applicationModuleVendorDependencies = ['ngResource', .... etc

You need to add 'ngFileUpload' to that list.  That defines the dependency for your module.

If you only do this, you'll get an error message:

> [$injector:nomod] Module 'ngFileUpload' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

ngFileUpload is defined in the script files that are in the ng-file-upload folders, so obviously angular can't know what ngFileUpload is unless it's being told where the files are on the file system, somehow.

b) Update all.js, found at /config/env/all.js

This is where you tell angular what files on the file system to include.  We need two lines, and they *may* need to be in a specific order (I read from other sources that they do, but that may have been from older versions).  In any case, in all.js, find

```
'public/lib/angular/angular.js',
```

and replace surround it like so:

```
'public/lib/ng-file-upload-shim/ng-file-upload-shim.min.js',
'public/lib/angular/angular.js',
'public/lib/ng-file-upload/ng-file-upload.min.js',
```

c) Inject the dependency into your module with the proper name

You might think that now, in your controller, you inject ngFileUpload, but the name you need to use for the injection is 'Upload'.

Here's a sample controller with the correct form:

```
controller('fileUploadTestCtrl', ['$scope','Upload',
function ($scope, Upload) {}
```

As you can see, it's called 'Upload'.  No dollar signs or anything else; an older version used $upload, but it was changed.

d) Enjoy

Hopefully this will be useful to someone stuck trying to figure this out.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Thank you chris c !!! Saved me hours ! SERIOUSLY !